# Which thermal circuit breaker should I buy?

Tags: electrical, screws, circuit-breaker

I live in a small house in Argentina where we use 220 volts. I have a thermal circuit breaker that do squeak noises when the iron starts or the fridge starts. I adjusted the four screws of the breaker but I saw it was broken. When I adjust one of the screw, it separate the plastic thermal circuit breaker. I would like to know why I have to adjust the screws periodically.
 I want to replace the circuit breaker because this breakage: what features should has the new one?

[image: This thermal circuit breaker is similar at mine]

Comment: "adjust the screws periodically" Does Australia by any chance permit aluminum wiring? In the US, this was a symptom of using aluminum wiring with copper rated terminations. Otherwise, if the screws are actually self loosening, it indicates a poor design.

Comment: @FiascoLabs, Argentina... 8)

Answer (score 1):

replace like with like.

look at the print on it and see what amperage it is rated for and get one with the same rating. the one picture is a double pole breaker that will shut down both leads when either one is overloaded.